# PHP is_file issue

Tags: php

I am using the below code :

```
$s_img = 'logoDSK1-1423585418.jpg';
$slogo = is_file('http://www.domain.nl/members/images/logo/' . $s_img) ?
        'http://domain.nl/images/logo/' . $s_img : false;
print $slogo ? $slogo : 'http://www.domain.nl/afbeeldingen/fotos/thumb_klein.jpg';
```

The file `http://domain.nl/images/logo/logoDSK1-1423585418.jpg` exists
but every time the code returns : `http://www.domain.nl/afbeeldingen/fotos/thumb_klein.jpg`

What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how [`is_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) works. It tells whether the given file is a regular file.

I use this little guy for what you need:

```
function remoteFileExists($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if (curl_exec($ch)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Use like:

```
if (remoteFileExists('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png')){
    echo 'Yay! Photo is there.';
} else {
    echo 'Photo no home.';
}
```

Or, in your case:

```
$slogo = remoteFileExists('http://www.domain.nl/members/images/logo/' . $s_img) ? 'http://domain.nl/images/logo/' . $s_img : false;
print $slogo ? $slogo : 'http://www.domain.nl/afbeeldingen/fotos/thumb_klein.jpg';
```